# InvalidOperationException when attempting to use database dependent policy Authorization in Blazor Server

Tags: .net, authorization, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to render content in Blazor to a user based on a `status` field of an entity related to the user in the database.

A simplified version of my database would look like this.

Users:

```
|userid|email|groupid|
|--| --- | ---- |
|1 | sta@example.com | 4 |
|2 | dany@example.com | 5 |
|3 | elle@example.com | 5 |
```

Groups:

```
|groupid|status|
|--| --- |
|4 | Active |
|5 | Inactive |
```

I have created an `AuthorizationHandler` and an `IAuthorizationRequirement`. I have left these out due to the wall of code that they and their dependencies would produce (will include if asked). The basic idea is that the `AuthorizationHandler` fetches the users group from the database and checks it against a requirement. For the requirements I have wired up two policies "Active" and "Inactive", which as their name implies grants access for that given status.

When trying to apply these in Blazor server using the `Authorize` attribute, like so:

```
<Authorize Policy = "Active">...</Authorize>
<Authorize Policy = "Inactive">...</Authorize>
```

I get back the error in the title: `InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed`.

However if I only use one of them it works fine.

It is also worth mentioning that I have wired up the `DbContext` as per the docs on ef in Blazor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<StateDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure()));
services.AddTransient<StateDbContext>(p => 
    p.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<StateDbContext>>()
        .CreateDbContext());
```

My questions are:

1. Is my solution (using policies) to solve this problem appropriate? I went with them for their reusability.
2. If I am onto something, what can I do to mitigate the issue of the DbContext being shared?
3. If I am doing something crazy, are there any alternative ways to achive this?

Thank you.

Comment: What does your component tree look like where these Authorization calls are made? It's quite a common pitfall to have two components using a DbContext at the same time.

Comment: @BenSampica That is exactly what I am doing. The components tree looks as specified above (let me know if you would like a more verbose version). Both Authorize attributes policies call the same service that shares the same DbContext.

Comment: What component is `<Authorize>`? That is not a built-in authorization component of [blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authorization-1).

Answer (score -1):

You're error is related to the execution of multiple operation against the same dbcontext.

Try to use a more *atomic* approach to the dbcontext.
This error is typically generated by Blazor Server apps that maintain a dbcontext without disposing it as soon as possible.

**After some test**

I've tried and I can confirm that the problem is your use of Dbcontext as I written.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, I understand that this is the cause of the issue, however I have other projects using the same services (which the DbContext is in turn used from) and manually disposing the context would affect all the other projects. Just to experiment I tired using transient lifetimes for the DbContext (which should have the same effect without forcing enormous refactroring efforts) and it did not help. It feels odd that I should have to manually dispose of my cotext to do his, therfore I feel like I might be going about this the wrong way.